# Visual Studio -

Tags: azure-devops

I'm very new to Visual Studio Team Services and had a couple of questions:

I'm using an Agile template and trying to check some features of tasks on the backlog boards.

- Is there any limitation to the history of a task e.g. if an attachment is deleted, how long will it stay accessible in the history tab? I want to protect file history and iterations, as multiple people will be accessing the same task and updating the file, but for quality reasons, I want to make sure I can see every version even if the attachment is deleted.

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed so! I've updated it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VSTS work item history always keeps each revision including the attachments.

So you can find each revision changes in work item History Tab. And download the attachments from a work item history revision if you need.